# How to use Android system FreeType library in native code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype

I use FreeType in my Android applications as a static library which i compile myself. I want to make my app smaller so i'm looking for a possibility to use the system version of FreeType. Is it possible to do? Is it a stable API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android#FreeType) it is not possible and requires you to cross compile the library.

> If you need FreeType (a library to render fonts), you'll need to cross-compile it. Note: The Android system uses FreeType but internally it doesn't expose it to native apps.